# mandar una impresion a diferentes impresoras conectadas a mi red local con php

Tags: php, print

tengo un html donde basicamente muestro una tabla y texto con alineaciones y estilos css
y lo que deseo es poder imprimirlo, actualmente lo hago con print de javascript pero lo que deseo es poder mediante php conectarme a las impresoras que estan en mi red local y asi enviar esta impresion a la impresora que corresponda.
Contexto:
tengo script que me genera una boleta html y en ese script le pongo con javascript el comando print y me imprime la pagina actual, yo lo que deseo es imprimir este mismo script pero enviarlo directamente a la impresora

Comment: ¿Tu servidor con PHP está en la misma red que tu impresora de red? Desde el navegador con Javascript no podrás saltar el cuadro de diálogo de impresión, y PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el servidor y no en el navegador. ¿Qué has intentado o averiguado? Tal como está redactada tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre.

Comment: enviate el html al php ( o generalo en php ) convertilo a pdf ( seteando las opciones de impresion ) y luego desde php mismo lo imprimis via socket -> `if($conn=fsockopen('ip.de.la.impresora',9100, $errno, $errstr)){fputs($conn, file_get_contents('file.pdf'), filesize('file.pdf'));}`

Comment: esto es en linux???

Answer (score 1):

Ante todo no puedes imprimir directamente un diseño/documento HTML y CSS...

Lo que si puedes hacer es convertir eso en PDF (esto puede ser otra pregunta que publiques) y el PDF si lo podrias enviar a imprimir a la impresora desde php con el comando LP de linux:

```
//Path y nombre del archivo
$files         = '/docs/pdf/archivo.pdf';

//nombre de la impresora en el sistema operativo
$printer       = 'nombre_impresora';

//numero de copias
$copias        = (!isset($cop)) ? 1 : $cop;

// Comando para imprimir el archivo PDF en la impresora especificada
$print_command = "lp -d $printer -n $copias $files -o notify 2>&1";
exec($print_command, $output, $return_var);
```

Si estas en un entorno Windows sugeriria implementar adobe acrobat reader:

```
$pdfFilePath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/docs/pdf/archivo.pdf'; // Ruta al archivo PDF
$printerName = 'nombre_impresora'; // Nombre de la impresora

// Comando para imprimir el archivo PDF en la impresora especificada
$printCommand = "AcroRd32.exe /t \"$pdfFilePath\" \"$printerName\"";

// Ejecutar el comando de impresión
exec($printCommand, $output, $returnVar);

// Verificar si la impresión fue exitosa
if ($returnVar === 0) {
    echo "El archivo PDF se ha enviado a la impresora para imprimir.";
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error al intentar imprimir el archivo PDF.";
}
```

Esto ultimo lo hago por que en su momento comence utilizando xampp

Comment: Hola, ayúdanos a responder preguntas que sean realizadas con base en [ask], esto para conservar la calidad en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys ok, entonces mi respuesta no es valida?

Comment: o el problema es la pregunta?

Comment: La pregunta, tal vez lo que respondes puede ser que no sea lo que necesite el OP, debería de aclarar lo que le preguntan los usuarios.

Comment: _deseo es imprimir este mismo script pero enviarlo directamente a la impresora_ esta es la pregunta final que realizo el usuario. lo cual es un concepto erroneo que hay que corregir y orientar con lo que si se puede hacer ... **vuelvo a preguntarte:  el hecho de que la pregunta sea mala o este mal plantada invalida mi respuesta? espero un si o un no.**

Comment: ¡Se agradece tu esfuerzo Walter!, pero en ocasiones responder a estas preguntas, hace que estos usuarios nuevos no se esfuercen y escriban constantemente preguntas de baja calidad, incluso las respuestas que les dan los usuarios ni siquiera son valoradas por el OP. Lo mejor es preguntar para aclarar y que agregué lo que trato o investigo.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover no es un concepto erróneo si php corre en la misma red local que las impresoras, eso es lo que falta aclarar, el resto son conjeturas

Comment: @aloMalbarez no entiendo tu comentario

Comment: el Op tiene un script en javascript el cual quiere agarrarlo y meterlo en php y obtener el html css para imprimir la boleta... esto es completamente erroneo, no puedes imprimir el script javascript ni meterlo dentro de php para que funcione y genere el hml css ... los conceptos expuesto estan desordenados y no son compatible con lo que al final pretende que seria la impresio de la boleta ...

Comment: esos conceptos se deben corregir y se debe guiar al OP a una correcta implementacion basado en el entorno de desarrollo.

Comment: esa es la conjetura. el titulo reza "mandar una impresion a diferentes impresoras conectadas a mi red local con php" luego describe la solución actual basada en javascript, la cual no le sirve.

Comment: entonces le digo como se hace desde php para linux con LP y desde windows con adobe acrobat reader ... no veo que tiene eso de malo... si tienes otro forma de hacerlo puedes agregarlo como respuesta ... y ver cual es la que soluciona el problema del OP

Comment: Tu respuesta está bien para esos entornos con esas herramientas. Mi solución basada en sockets está como comentario.